# Can't find the limit of this sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

New to calculus and kinda stuck on this sequence:
$$a_1= 1,\quad a_{n+1}= \frac{{a_n}^2 + 4}4.$$
So far I believe I was able to prove that it grows in size, and is therefore monotonic, and that no element is greater than 2, therefore it converges. But how can I find the limit?

Comment: I tend to think that both a(n) and a(n+1) tend to the same limit (loosely speaking) and so $L=(L+4)/4$ so you can calculate $L$. $L$ is the limit

Comment: If the limit $L$ exists, then it must satisfy $$L=(L+4)/4$$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type in a(n) squared, if it makes a difference. Also, why must it satisfy that?

Comment: If $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$, and $f$ is continuous, and $L=\lim_n a_n$ exists, then you can take limits on both sides to obtain $L=f(L)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $L=(L^2+4)/4$?

Comment: @Alan Indeed I believe it should. Especially since that makes the solution simple, as you get $4L = L^2 + 4 \implies L = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=L$, we can see that as $n\to \infty$, $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ both $\to L$ (because as $n\to \infty$, $n+1\to \infty$).

This is useful because $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=L=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(a_n)^2+4}{4}=\dfrac{(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n)^2+4}{4}=\dfrac{L^2+4}{4}$. So we have $$L=\dfrac{L^2+4}{4}$$

Solve for $L$, we get $L=2$. Hopefully it helped.

Comment: Thanks man, that was really clear!